# Confused with how to set Cname records

Tags: dns, server, nameserver

Here is a screenshot of what cPanel is asking for in Cname records:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiUid.png

This is what i'm trying to do:

point: secure.randomdomain.com => secure.mydomain.com

What settings would I put to make that happen?

Comment: What is "it?" If you can tell us what control panel that is(eg. cPanel, Plesk, etc.) or even what host/registrar is responsible, it might be possible to point you at specific documentation.

Comment: it's cPanel that is asking for the Configuration

Comment: If you want to _redirect_ then a CNAME is not the thing to do. Now, sure, you may set a CNAME but you ALSO have to set rewrite rules. I do believe cPanel has options for "web forward" or something?

Comment: I don't really want a redirect, I want secure.randomdomain.com and secure.mydomain.com to be used inter-changeably.  I heard the only way to do that was a CName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under "Add a CNAME Record", enter `secure.randomdomain.com.` in the "Name" field and `secure.mydomain.com.` in the "CNAME" field and click "Add CNAME Record".

Don't put anything in the "Add an A Record" fields.

The CNAME record just means that the browser (OS really) will look up the first domain (the one in the "Name" field) and find a second domain name (the one in the "CNAME" field) rather than the IP address it was hoping to find. The browser will then look up that CNAME domain in hopes of finding an IP address.

So, the alternative way to do this is to know the IP address of `secure.mydomain.com` and use that in `secure.randomdomain.com`'s A record rather than creating a CNAME record. However, CNAME records work just fine, and in my experience, there's no reason not to use them.

UPDATED: note the trailing dots for both the "Name" field and the "CNAME" field.

Comment: shouldn't the value of the "Name" field end with a dot? like secure.randomdomain.com.

Comment: @amaters Yes! Actually both fields need the trailing dot. Thank you for pointing out that omission. I will update the answer.